# Pattern for using Dapper typed QueryAsync with stored procedure return codes

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

I'm running into a situation with Dapper calling a stored procedure where it does some validation logic, updates a row, then returns the results of the row as a strongly-typed POCO.

The problem lies in the validation logic, as there are multiple exit conditions where I want to return an error code for a given situation - and when Dapper `QueryAsync` does not receive a result set that matches the given POCO then it throws an `InvalidOperationException`.

(Before anybody comments on mixing logic in with the stored procedure, I understand the concern here but at this point it is unavoidable due to strict performance constraints. The design is not the issue to address.)

How can Dapper handle a stored procedure that can return either a POCO or an error code?

I haven't seen anything in Dapper tutorials about reading stored procedure return codes when using `QueryAsync<T>`.

So my initial thought is to do something like this (pseudocode below):

1. Stored procedure: make it always return POCO columns as the first result set (`SELECT TOP 0 FROM PocoTable`)
2. Stored procedure: then `SELECT -1 AS ErrorCode` as the final result set
3. C# repository: instead of doing `conn.QueryAsync<Poco>()`  do `conn.QueryMultiple()`, then `ReadAsync<Poco>`, and if that returns null then `ReadAsync<int>` for the error code

Is there a better way to handle this?

Example code here:

(note that this is pseudocode and only meant to convey the idea, not actually be an executable example - please don't comment on correcting syntax or usage)

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SwapData
    @ID1 INT,
    @ID2 INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Count INT
    DECLARE @Swap Table 
                  (
                      [ID] INT Identity(1,1),
                      [PocoID] INT,
                      [MyData] [nvarchar](255)
                  )

    INSERT INTO @Swap
        SELECT PocoID, MyData 
        FROM PocoTable 
        WHERE PocoID IN (@ID1, @ID2)

    SELECT @Count = COUNT(1) FROM @Swap

    IF @Count <> 2
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 0 NULL FROM PocoTable
        SELECT -1 AS ErrorCode
        RETURN -1 -- never used in C# just returning non-0 for convention
    END

    UPDATE ORIG
    SET ORIG.MyData = swap.MyData
    FROM PocoTable AS ORIG 
    INNER JOIN @Swap AS swap ON (ORIG.PocoID = @ID1 AND swap.ID = 2)
                             OR (ORIG.PocoID = @ID2 AND swap.ID = 1)

    SELECT PocoID, MyData 
    FROM PocoTable 
    WHERE PocoID = @ID1
END
```

Repository:

```
public class Repo
{
    public Task<Poco> SwapData(int targetId, int sourceId)
    {
        using (var conn = GetSqlConnection())
        {
            await conn.OpenAsync();
            var mrs = await conn.QueryMultipleAsync(
                "dbo.SwapData", 
                new { ID1 = targetId, ID2 = sourceId }, 
                commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

            var result = await mrs.ReadFirstOrDefaultAsync<TType>();
            if (result != null) return result;

            var errorCode = await mrs.ReadFirstAsync<int>();

            throw new PocoRepositorySwapException(errorCode);
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I've discovered a nice solution that works *synchronously* but NOT *asynchronously*!

Stored procedure w/ simple return:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SwapData
    @ID1 INT,
    @ID2 INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Count INT
    DECLARE @Swap Table 
                  (
                      [ID] INT Identity(1,1),
                      [PocoID] INT,
                      [MyData] [nvarchar](255)
                  )

    INSERT INTO @Swap
        SELECT PocoID, MyData 
        FROM PocoTable 
        WHERE PocoID IN (@ID1, @ID2)

    SELECT @Count = COUNT(1) FROM @Swap

    IF @Count <> 2
    BEGIN
        RETURN -1
    END

    UPDATE ORIG
    SET ORIG.MyData = swap.MyData
    FROM PocoTable AS ORIG 
    INNER JOIN @Swap AS swap ON (ORIG.PocoID = @ID1 AND swap.ID = 2)
                             OR (ORIG.PocoID = @ID2 AND swap.ID = 1)

    SELECT PocoID, MyData 
    FROM PocoTable 
    WHERE PocoID = @ID1
END
```

Repository (synchronous, works):

```
public class Repo
{
    public Task<Poco> SwapData(int targetId, int sourceId)
    {
        using (var conn = GetSqlConnection())
        {
            var p = new { ID1 = targetId, ID2 = sourceId };
            var pWithReturnValue = new DynamicParameters(p);
            p.Add("return", null, DbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
            // no exception when synchronous
            var result = conn.Query<Poco>("dbo.SwapData", p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

            var errorCode = p.Get<int>("return");
            if (errorCode != 0)
                throw new SwapRepositoryException(errorCode);

            return result.FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Repository (asynchronous, Dapper exception):

```
public class Repo
{
    public Task<Poco> SwapData(int targetId, int sourceId)
    {
        using (var conn = GetSqlConnection())
        {
            var p = new { ID1 = targetId, ID2 = sourceId };
            var pWithReturnValue = new DynamicParameters(p);
            p.Add("return", null, DbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
            // "InvalidOperationException: No columns were selected" happens here when async
            var result = await conn.QueryAsync<Poco>("dbo.SwapData", p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

            var errorCode = p.Get<int>("return");
            if (errorCode != 0)
                throw new SwapRepositoryException(errorCode);

            return result.FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

The only change is the Query to QueryAsync, and that results in an InvalidOperationException.

Comment: Did you try it with another stored procedure?

Comment: the sproc is not the issue, I can reproduce it with a simple sproc and by temporarily inserting a RETURN statement

Comment: I've split the bottom half off into another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45965438/why-does-dapper-queryasynct-behave-differently-from-queryt-with-sproc-return