# Why does Dapper QueryAsync<T> behave differently from Query<T> with sproc return values?

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

I have a stored procedure that performs a check, and returns either a row or a non-zero return value:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ConditionalGet
    @ID INT
AS
BEGIN

    -- this is a silly made up condition just to test the issue
    IF @ID % 2 = 1
    BEGIN
        RETURN -1
    END

    SELECT *
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE ID = @ID

    RETURN 0
END
```

And I have a C# repo class that uses Dapper to return the result or throw an exception:

```
public class Repo
{
    public MyClass Get(int id)
    {
        using (var conn = GetSqlConnection())
        {
            var p = new { ID = id };
            var pWithReturnValue = new DynamicParameters(p);
            p.Add("return", null, DbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);

            var result = conn.Query<MyClass>("dbo.ConditionalGet", p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

            var errorCode = p.Get<int>("return");
            if (errorCode != 0)
                throw new RepositoryGetException(errorCode);

            return result.FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

And this works as expected: when id is divisible by 2, the hydrated object is returned, otherwise an exception is thrown.

HOWEVER, this fails when I make the code Async!

```
public class Repo
{
    public async Task<MyClass> Get(int id)
    {
        using (var conn = GetSqlConnection())
        {
            var p = new { ID = id };
            var pWithReturnValue = new DynamicParameters(p);
            p.Add("return", null, DbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
            // this is the only change!
            var result = await conn.QueryAsync<MyClass>("dbo.ConditionalGet", p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

            var errorCode = p.Get<int>("return");
            if (errorCode != 0)
                throw new RepositoryGetException(errorCode);

            return result.FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

This throws an InvalidOperationException "No columns were selected"!

I really like the pattern here and would like to use it asynchronously, so why the failure? I've tried turning buffering off and on and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: I have no idea, but you should not use stored procedure return values directly from client code.  Instead use errors (throw, raiserror) to indicate success or failure in the stored procedure, or consume the return value in your TSQL batch and raise an error on a non-zero return value.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Dapper doesn't support for Async methods that no perform a SELECT statement.
There is a open issue about that in Github:
https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/issues/591

What you do for now is something like:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.ConditionalGet
    @ID INT,
    @Output INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN

    -- this is a silly made up condition just to test the issue
    IF @ID % 2 = 1
    BEGIN
        SET @Output = -1
    END
    ELSE BEGIN
        SET @Output = 0
    END

    SELECT *
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE ID = @ID
END
```